# How to auto-expand excel-workbook containing multiple sheets using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to auto-expand the Excel file using the python script but it's throwing some error. Requesting your help here.

I have tried with below code.

```
            import openpyxl
            from string import ascii_uppercase

            newFile = "C:\\Users\\subhendu.a.panda\\Documents\\Details.xlsx"

            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = newFile)
            worksheet = wb.active

            for col in worksheet.columns:
                max_length = 0
                column = col[0].column # Get the column name
                for cell in col:
                    if cell.coordinate in worksheet.merged_cells: # not check merge_cells
                        continue
                    try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
                        if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                            max_length = len(cell.value)
                    except:
                        pass
                adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
                worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
                wb.save(newFile)
```

It's throwing below error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/subhendu.a.panda/Desktop/myvenv/myV/expandExcel.py", line 21, in 
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
  File "C:\Users\subhendu.a.panda\Desktop\myvenv\myV\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\bound_dictionary.py", line 26, in **getitem**
    setattr(value, self.reference, key)
  File "C:\Users\subhendu.a.panda\Desktop\myvenv\myV\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 44, in **set**
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
TypeError: expected

Comment: The exception looks incomplete.

Comment: Exception details :   expandExcel.py", line 21, in <module>
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width

Comment: Excption 2 : openpyxl\utils\bound_dictionary.py", line 26, in __getitem__
    setattr(value, self.reference, key)    .... for the code :   
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super(BoundDictionary, self).__getitem__(key)
        if self.reference is not None:
            setattr(value, self.reference, key)
        return value

Comment: Exception 3 : openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 44, in __set__
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))   is against the code ::        def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            if (not self.allow_none
                or (self.allow_none and value is not None)):
                raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        super(Typed, self).__set__(instance, value)

Answer (score 0):

It's got resolved. Thanks guys for your support.

the error was like it was fetching the column number not the column name previously that leads to type error. I've used the col.column_letter with col.column as below and I got the expected o/p.

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = col[0].column_letter # Get the column name
    for cell in col:
        if cell.coordinate in worksheet.merged_cells: # not check merge_cells
            continue
        try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(cell.value)
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
    wb.save(newFile)
```